# How to replace toPromise on a Service Call?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently maintaining some code that calls a service using the following code:

```js
getCommonData() {
    const facility_id = this._router.snapshot.params.id;
    this._generalService.getFacilityCommonData(facility_id).toPromise().then(res => {
      this.commonData = res.data;
    })
}
```

The service code being called returns an HTTP response like this:

```js
getFacilityCommonData(facility_id?: any): any {
    const params = { facility_id: facility_id }
    const httpOptions = {
      params: facility_id? params : null
    };
    return this.http.get(`${apiUrl}/${version}/fetch/common/data/`, httpOptions).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
    }));
}
```

This code works but takes too long to return and once the call returns all the GUI has already been rendered and can no longer use the response.

I have tried to replace the current code with the following code:

```js
this.commonData = this._generalService.getFacilityCommonData(facility_id).data;
```

This returns in time to use the data but I cannot use the returned value or have access to the data in it.

My question is: How can I replace the call using `toPromise` so I get the return in time and still have access to the data?

Comment: Instead of trying to change an async function to run synchronously you should try to change your component to re-render as soon as the data is available. That should not be a problem with angular.

Comment: Can you post the code of the component that uses common data...or show how this is further used and why you can't wait for the `getFacilityCommonData` function to finish

Comment: why not wrap div with ngIf="!common?.data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: How can I replace the call using toPromise so I get the return in time and still have access to the data?

This question is misleading because if you're using toPromise to try to guarantee an event in-time, the bulk of the work is the result of a HTTP network call being inconsistently slow. Converting this Observable to a Promise within here won't help you.

---

What do developer tools say is the duration of that get request? This can be found in any modern browser by opening the developer tools, finding the "Network" option, finding the get request this sends and clicking on the Timings interface to get a sense on how the network request takes as well.

```
   return this.http.get(`${apiUrl}/${version}/fetch/common/data/`, httpOptions).pipe(map(res => {
    return res;
  }));
```

In the service code provided, the pipe and map operators add a very mild layer being added with the extra pipe that doesn't provide any value since it's just passing through res, but the overhead is small and would not compare to the duration the http request would take to send it over the network, that API to process it, and then return it.

The rest of the answer is making an assumption that the code that calls this service is written in an Angular component that has an entry in an Angular routing module file.

I'd recommend considering whether the commonData field is so important to the component that it is worth waiting for this get request to finish before even initially loading the component. If so, creating a resolver to call this service and declaring it in the routing module, which can then be accessed through ActivatedRoute inside the compnent. [Angular documentation has a long-winded example of it in its Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your view/GUI component is not properly programmed to either wait for the data or to refresh when data is loaded.

I would suggest to review your approach.

Depending on your program you could for example simplify using AsyncPipe:

```
this.commonData$: Observable<YourType | any> =
    this._generalService.getFacilityCommonData(facility_id);
```

and then in your view:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="commonData$ | async as commonData; else loading">
   ... your data related view here ...
</ng-container>


<ng-template #loading>
    Loading ...
</ng-template>
```

Have a look at:

https://angular.io/guide/http

Or you could use your existing function and add a boolean flag
e.g:

```
    isDataLoaded: boolean;


    getCommonData() {
    const facility_id = this._router.snapshot.params.id;
    this._generalService.getFacilityCommonData(facility_id).toPromise().then(res => {
      this.commonData = res.data;
      this.isDataLoaded = true;
    })
```

and then in your view:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isDataLoaded; else loading">
   ... your data related view here ...
</ng-container>


<ng-template #loading>
    Loading ...
</ng-template>
```

This really is just an assumed approach and depends on the logic and flow of your app.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and unfortunately it did not work. This is looking to me to be more of a data issue then a GUI issue.